# Instantiating WPF objects and making them available

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

Below is some startup code to instantiate a ResourceManager for a WPF application. If I wanted this made available via xaml, would I put it in a resource dictionary? Use ObjectProvider? Something else?

Is there a reason to prefer one method of object instantiation over another in a WPF app?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
var asm = Assembly.Load("SampleApp.Common");
var resourceMan = new ResourceManager("SampleApp.Common.Resources.SupportedCultures", asm);
DataContext = new MainWindowVm(resourceMan);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the static class is the best solution if you don't need to replace dictionary during application lifetime:

```
public static class SampleAppCommonResources
{
    private static ResourceManager _Manager;

    public static ResourceManager Manager
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Manager == null)
            {
                var asm = Assembly.Load("SampleApp.Common");
                _Manager = new ResourceManager("SampleApp.Common.Resources.SupportedCultures", asm);
            }

            return _Manager;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML usage:

```
<Menu Tag="{x:Static local:SampleAppCommonResources.Manager}">
```

If there is multi-threaded environment, `_Manager` should be assigned using `Interlocked.CompareExchange` for instance.